# Reduce ios keyboard height

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, iphone-6, facebook-messenger

How can I reduce the height of keyboard in iOS? I couldn't find any api that I can use to achieve this objective.

My client noticed that Facebook messenger and builtin iMessage app on iPhone 6 has a keyboard which is a little bit small in height than keyboard in my app. Is it because they are using custom keyboard or there is a way in iPhone 6 to reduce the height?

I am posting screenshots below from both apps so that you can compare them.

This is from Facebook messenger app.
http://postimg.org/image/h6u1jt5db/

This is from my app.
http://postimg.org/image/j8q5tw9if/

Comment: another thing you didn't notice that you status bar looks bold then other native apps.just need to add splash screen for iphone 6 and 6+ and your keyboard and status bar issue will be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah just add splash screen for iphone 6 and 6+ your application and your keyboard height and status bar height will be decrease. strange but true.

Answer (score -1):

There is possibility of Custom keyboard in Facebook messenger and builtin iMessage from ios8.

You can easily provide custom keyboard with the theme which your app  suits.

You can take a look at [HERE](http://www.appcoda.com/custom-keyboard-tutorial/)