# IOS - make app scale

Tags: ios, user-interface, interface, size

I want to make an application, that have big and clear UI (Like GrabTAXI). In app, every element have big font, i.e: Status bar, keyboard etc. 
I try to change font, size of every element, but I think it have other way.

Help me, anyone?

Comment: for 6 and 6+ scale , just remove the launch image for 6 and 6+ ,and show the magic.

Comment: you can refer this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643549/reduce-ios-keyboard-height/29643790#29643790

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be use AutoLayout in your project.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

This is the best way.

Comment: Yeap, I used AutoLayout already. But I think it is another solution for this :). Anyway, thanks

Comment: if you used 'Autolayout' and you want to change the font of text, size of every document...ect, You should check with the current device.
For example: If you want to change frame of navigation bar with iPhone 6.

`#define IS_IPHONE6 (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-667)?NO:YES)`
`if(IS_IPHONE6) {
     self.navigationController.view.frame.size.width - 48
}`